# text texturing problem

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

[image]i added the texture to the text, but the texture only shows off at the top of the text. How can i fix this problem?[image]

[image]pg

Answer (score 1):

For the moment your object is still a *Text* object. To be able to project the image texture on all its 3 axis you need to either:

- Use the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate* and switch the *Image Texture* from *Flat* to *Box*, put the *Blend* at 1 (you can scale, rotate or move the texture in the *Mapping* node):

[image]

- Convert it to a mesh object (<kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Convert To > Mesh*), then you can for example do a <kbd>U</kbd> > *Cube Projection*. If you need to adjust the texture differently, open the *UV Editor* and move the UV faces.

Comment: i love you... searched this for a days